# c# changing window size automatically

Tags: c#, winforms

I am a student working on a windows forms application. In this application I have a form like a pop up window that shows a label. I want to change that window's size according to label's size. For example if the label has 3 lines, it should show all of the lines automatically. But right now it shows only one line. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: [Please have a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962595/how-do-you-resize-a-form-to-fit-its-content-automatically) and [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672978/how-to-autosize-the-height-of-a-label-but-not-the-width).

Comment: This should be useful: 
[Link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185557/my-windows-forms-application-size-is-changing-different-notebooks)

Comment: You can do this with standard properties available in the designer.  Set the form's AutoSize property True, AutoSizeMode to GrowAndShrink.  To get more than one "line" out of the label, you'll have to set its MaximumSize property to, say, (100, 0) so it is forced to wrap the text.

Comment: @EcehanEce welcome to Stack Overflow.Still having problem in implementing solution in project. you can ask your query in comment if you have? if you already have solved the problem then mark that answer accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to calculate the size of the text using the font settings of the label in your pop-up form. Here's an example of the pop-up form's `Load` event:

```
    private void Popup_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        messageLabel.Text = TextToShow;

        Graphics gfx = this.CreateGraphics();
        SizeF textSize = gfx.MeasureString(messageLabel.Text, messageLabel.Font);

        Size borders = this.Size - this.ClientSize;

        this.Size = new Size((int)textSize.Width, (int)textSize.Height) + borders;            
    }
```

This code presumes you have a property called `TextToShow` to pass the message to be displayed to the form:

```
        public string TextToShow { get; set; }
```

You can open the pop-up form like this:

```
        Popup popup = new Popup();
        popup.TextToShow = "Test\nMult-line popup window\n\nLine4\n\nLine 6";

        popup.ShowDialog(this);
```

The pop-up form will scale to the label's size. Try adjusting fonts, changing text, etc - should work correctly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Eh, yours could be useful... I'm sure it can :p